# Using Generialization with Serializable Objects

Tags: java, serialization, sonarlint

Let's say you have the following code, you'll get a warning about raw types.

```
public class Test implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -793775208204855910L;
    private List dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(Object data) {
        dataList.add(data);
    }
}
```

So you change it and you declare dataList to be a list of Objects. You don't get any more warning because it's not using raw types anymore. But then Sonar complains because you're not using a Serialized List of Objects since you have a Serialized Class.

```
public class test implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -793775208204855910L;
    private List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(Object data) {
        dataList.add(data);
    }
}
```

So you change the List declaration so that objects are implementing Serializable, but then you can't add Objects to the list anymore.

```
public class test implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -793775208204855910L;
    private List<? extends Serializable> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(Object data) {
        dataList.add(data); //<--Doesn't compile, gives an error
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I can use Generalization with Serialized Objects which won't generate warnings or errors in Java and Sonar?

Comment: Change the `add(Object data)` method signature to `add(Serializable data)` to make sure that only serializable objects are added to the list.

Comment: You can also add the `transient` modifier to the definition of your `dataList`, so it will no longer be serialized - if that is what you want.

Comment: @Jack If I use `add(Serializable data)`, I get the following error:The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Serializable) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Serializable> is not applicable for the arguments (Serializable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that an Object per se is not Serializable. So try to declare the Method parameter as Serializable or an implementation of it.
Solution 1:
Get rid of the ? and use Serializable direct:

```
private List<Serializable> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
public void add(Serializable data) {
  dataList.add(data);
}
```

Solution 2:
If you like to keep th ? try:

```
public <T extends Serializable> void add(T data) {
  dataList.add(data);
}
```

Anyway, if you declare it as a List of Serializables you need to fill it with Serializables and not any Object.

Comment: So using `private List<Serializable> dataList = new ArrayList<>(); public <T extends Serializable> void add(T data) {dataList.add(data);}`
`